# Codons and numbers

Tags: r, numbers, genetic

everyboy. I am a beginner with R. I´d like to ask how could you assign a codon to a number
I mean this:
AAA is 1
AAC is 2
AAG is 3
AAT or AAU is 4 
.
.
.
And subsequently. Thanks to everybody

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
BASES = c("A","C","G","T")
triN = apply(expand.grid(BASES,BASES,BASES),1,paste,collapse="")
data.frame(number=1:length(triN),codon=sort(triN))

   number codon
1       1   AAA
2       2   AAC
3       3   AAG
4       4   AAT
5       5   ACA
6       6   ACC
7       7   ACG
8       8   ACT
9       9   AGA
10     10   AGC
11     11   AGG
12     12   AGT
```

Comment: Yes, something like that and the with all the condons. It will be better in alphabetic orden.

Comment: @LorenzoGutiérrezAvilés, Something like the edited?

Comment: Exactly that´s the way

Answer (score 1):

```
bases <- c("A","C","G","T")
x <- levels(interaction(bases,bases,bases, sep = ""))
x <- x[order(x)]
data.frame(number=1:length(x), codon=x)
```